# Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Hi I am creating a jsp project using netbeans and whenever I try to run the project I get the following error

```
"Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 40; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."
```

Could somebody please help me debug it?

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandleMapping"/>
        <bean id="urlMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
    <bean name="indexController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
    </beans>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="../../css/style.css>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `mvc:resources` and you don't have `namespace` and `schemaLocation` defined for the same.

Also, you mentioned `mvc:resources` outside beans definition. Try with below one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandleMapping" />

    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="../../css/style.css" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the format of your dispatcher-servlet.xml is wrong, in the root element. You didnt close the xsi:schemaLocation namespace. Please try to use the corrected xml given below

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandleMapping"/>
        <bean id="urlMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
    <bean name="indexController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
    </beans>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="../../css/style.css>
```

Comment: @Klyan I had noticed and edited that but the bug still persists. I have edited my question to reflect the edits in the source code .Please have a look . Thanks